# set --no-color to default for git in the command line

Tags: git, git-config

I am working on embedded systems that don't have color in the terminal (stripped busybox).  When I am working with git I always have to remember the --no-color option.

I know that I can set me email by settings

```
git config user.email
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to do something similar to set so that I won't have to add that every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`color.ui` is the option you need:

```
$ git config color.ui false
```

(also, consider using the `--global` flag if you have multiple repositories on the same box)

Comment: Worked awesome!  Thanks!